# Python: pass an item's value instead of it's name

Tags: python

This has to be asked somewhere already, but I don't know the right words to find or frame it. So please bear with me.

This code fragment:

```
code = 'VegCode'

d = {}
codes = foo_func

for item in codes:
    print item.code
```

Results in:

```
RuntimeError: Row: Field code does not exist
```

if I change it like this, it will work, but I don't want to hard code the variable name:

```
for item in codes:
    print item.VegCode
```

How do I pass the *value* of `code` to the `item` object instead of it's name? (and please tell me what key words would have led to an answer!)

Comment: This isn't enough code to figure out exactly what you're trying to do.  What is `foo_func`?

Comment: The keywords were: `python access attribute by name`.

Comment: @iiSeymour foo_func is [SearchCursor (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000050000000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getattr: `getattr(item, code)`

Keywords: how to access object's attribute by its name